# how to navigate nested objects of unknown depth?

Tags: javascript

Im making a notetaking app and Ive decided to store all the notes and structure in JSON file. On javascript, I get the JSON with AJAX, parse it and output it on the website.

My note structure is array of objects that can be nested, like this (if it is a note, it has a "content" attribute, if it is a folder, it has an array of objects (can be empty array too if the folder should me empty):

```
data {
  entries = [
    {
     name: "Some note",
     content: "This is a test note"
    },
    {
     name: "folder",
     children: [
       {
         name: "Bread recpie",
         content: "Mix flour with water..."
       },
       {
         name: "Soups",
         children: [
          {
            name: "Pork soup",
            content: "Add meat, onion..."
          },
          {
            name: "Chicken soup"
            content: "....."
          }
         ] 
       }
     ]
    }
  ]
}
```

To list the root directory, its simple, i just loop through the array as it only outputs the top-level records:

```
for (entry of data.entries) {
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = entry.name;
    if (entry.children) {
        li.className = "folder";
    } else {
        li.className = "file";
    }
    loop.appendChild(li); 
}
```

But what about the folders? How should I proceed in listing the folders if the depth of nesting is unknown? And how do I target the specific folder? Should I add unique IDs to every object so i can filter the array with them? Or should I store some kind of depth information in a variable all the time?

Comment: Please ask only one question, and make it concrete. What is the output you expect?

Comment: Wrap your loop in a function with `entries` as a parameter. Call this function for every entry that is a folder -> What have you already tried to solve this on your own?

Comment: @trincot I need a loop function that outputs only objects whose parent object has been send to said function (display folder's content)
Andreas -  Well this is the new model, my previous notes model was a 1-level array of objects and every note had a property "hasChildren" and "isParent" by which i determined the structure, but it had a duplication problem

Comment: Please show your failed attempt at writing that function. Please update your question (should be one question, should show efforts, expected output).

Comment: SO has already a bunch of [similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+object+traverse*unknown*depth*site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Comment: Please update question with a sample output you would like to see for `data.entries`

Answer (score 0):

You're making this more difficult for yourself by saving data to a JSON file. That is not a good approach. What you need to do is design a database schema appropriate for your data and create an API that outputs a predictable pattern of data that your client can work with.

I would suggest having a `Folder` resource and a `Note` resource linked through a one-to-many relationship. Each `Folder` resource can have many associated `Note` entries, but each `Note` has only one `Folder` that it is linked to. I suggest using an ORM, because most make it easy to eager load related data. For instance, if you choose Laravel you can use Eloquent, and then getting all notes for a folder is as easy as:

```php
$folderWithNotes = Folder::with('notes')->where('name', 'school-notes')->get();
```

Knowing PHP is beside the point. You should still be able to see the logic of that.

If you create a database and build a server-side API to handle your data, you will end up with JSON on your client side that has a predictable format and is easy to work with.

Comment: How does a "database" change the fact that a folder can have another folder as a child? Without a depth restriction? o.O

Comment: _"you will end up with JSON on your client side that has a predictable format and is easy to work with"_ - You will end up with the exact same structure OP already has. Folders with subfolders with subfolders ...

Comment: Also, assigning unique ids and other metadata for folders and notes becomes a cinch when you are using a database, especially together with an ORM. Do yourself a favour and don't save things in JSON files on the server side. JSON on your server is only for config files.

Comment: @Andreas I can't help OP with that. I suggested a simpler setup. He can take my advice and then figure out how to create nested folders if he wants. But regardless, saving to JSON files is a bad idea for this project.

Comment: _"saving to JSON files is a bad idea"_ - Why? What's the problem with a simple `JSON.parse()` to get all notes and folders as an actual object? Or `JSON.stringify()` to get the content back into a file?

Comment: @Andreas It's not scalable to save all your data to a single file. It's also not what JSON is for. It's not a method of data storage, except in the case of a limited amount of data like a config file. Data storage is the domain of databases. I would also say that OP needs to ask himself if nested folders is really needed. Thinking about it more, that may be more effort than it's worth especially if this is a hobby project, which it must be.

Comment: Thanks for this tip, but i specifically use JSON and a single-file (for all my life text notes, its perfectly scalable even with thousands of records) because my note taking app encrypts the whole array with cryptoJS to a single string that is then saved on the server. when reading, it is pulled, string is decrypted and parsed back. this is purposly build flat-file no-database no-metadata-on-server project.